# Another Next Number Question

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, number-sequence, poetry

This is a bit different number sequence.  Format and punctuation are on purpose.

What are the blanks?

```
4
1 2 2

'1 2, 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1:
1 2 1 1 3, _ _ _ _ _.
```

Hint 1:

> Going down the rabbit hole may lead to a clue.

Also added the knowledge tag.  The other odd tag is another hint.

Comment: Welcome To Puzzling SE! :D

Comment: @NL628 I prefer to call it PuzzlingOverflow :)

Comment: (Nice puzzle concept! A suggestion for future submissions: Without the hint, this probably wasn't solvable. Puzzles should be forward-solvable from information they contain, not desperate exercises in "guess what the setter was thinking", and should contain all the information needed to solve in the initial post. If vital information is added later in a "hint", that's not a hint, it's a fundamental part of the puzzle and needs to be there to start!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to do this without the hint, as I was searching in all the wrong holes. The numbers should be:

> , 1 1 1 1 2.
>
>  These are the syllable counts of the first stanza of the poem Jabberwocky by Lewis Carroll.
>  While I am not familiar with his work, I became familiar with many other poems in search of the matching pattern.

Comment: Congrats! Hope you had fun.